# Mercurial 404 error on a open source code repository

Tags: mercurial, http-status-code-404

I am new to Mercurial tool. I need to get the source code here

https://hg01.codeplex.com/mvcforum/file/4957efb70643

for a project reference. But when I type the command, I got the 404 error,

is there anything wrong with my command?

```
hg clone --verbose https://hg01.codeplex.com/mvcforum/file/4957efb70643 C:\
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
hg clone --verbose https://hg01.codeplex.com/mvcforum C:\
```

optionally, if you want to specify revision number use:

```
hg clone --verbose https://hg01.codeplex.com/mvcforum -r REV C:\
```

Try

```
hg help clone
```

for more details